# Streamlit hello error. Can't access streamlit properly (mac)

Tags: python, macos, pip, pipenv, streamlit

This is what i typed into the terminal

```
(python_streamlit) kaipo@Kaipos-MacBook-Pro python_streamlit % streamlit hello
```

This is the return i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaipo/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_streamlit-XyirRlP5/bin/streamlit", line 5, in <module>
    from streamlit.web.cli import main
  File "/Users/kaipo/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_streamlit-XyirRlP5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from streamlit.proto.RootContainer_pb2 import RootContainer
  File "/Users/kaipo/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_streamlit-XyirRlP5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/proto/RootContainer_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/Users/kaipo/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_streamlit-XyirRlP5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kaipo/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_streamlit-XyirRlP5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN6google8protobuf15FieldDescriptor12TypeOnceInitEPKS1_
  Referenced from: /Users/kaipo/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_streamlit-XyirRlP5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/kaipo/.local/share/virtualenvs/python_streamlit-XyirRlP5/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-310-darwin.so
```

I have already done

```
pipenv shell
```

to use the new streamlit environment

It is also at the newest update and the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock is in my folder. I'm also on macOS.

Would appreciate any ideas on this thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your protobuf version is not compatible. Try installing this version:

```
protobuf = ">=3.6.0, !=3.11"
```

Comment: How would i install this, been searching the internet and i can't find a solution

Comment: Create a new enviroment to test this solution, and then, install with this command:
*pip install protobuf==3.6.0* you must not install the version 3.11.